# Testing a Visual Studio Extension from VS2017 with the devenv for previous versions of Visual Studio does not work

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, devenv

I have a Visual Studio Extension, and if I test it in VS 2017 with the VS2017 devenv configured, then when I debug it launches an instance of VS2017 with my extension installed. However if I use the devenv for any of the older versions, the instance of visual studio it spins up does not have my extension. In VS2015, I was able to successfully do this with ease.

I suspect it has something to do with the SDK version.

When I inspect `%localappdata%/Microsoft/VisualStudio ...`, I see an experimental instance for version 15.0 that contains my extension. I believe it should be creating the experimental instance for the version of the targeted devenv.

Is there anything that I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Setting a (experimental) version of Visual Studio to debug in Project properties, Debug tab, Start External Program does not make the MSBuild targets of the VSSDK to deploy the extension to that (experimental) instance after creating the VSIX file in the output folder. That deployment is an independent thing controlled through MSBuild properties in the Visual Studio project file (ex: .csproj) such as "VisualStudioVersion".

You have a complete current guide for VS 2015/2017 here:

[Roundtrip Extensions for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-roundtrip-vsixs?view=vs-2017)

And something older in this GitHub project:

[RoundTripVSIX](https://github.com/jaredpar/RoundTripVSIX)